# accessing a set inside a set in raphael js

Tags: javascript, svg, raphael

I'm in the process of creating a little 'infographic' using raphael js. The infographic will render a number of circles with some text inside. The number of circles isn't know and will depend on the data it gets fed.

I thought that I would organise the raphael objects into sets, one for each circle and then move those sets into one 'container' set but I am having trouble accessing them programatically using something like:

```
console.log(ss[0].circle);
```

Here is a snippet of the code im using to draw my circles/add them to a set:

```
var r = Raphael('raph', '500px', '500px');

var coord = {
'0': {x: 177, y: 75},
'1': {x: 420, y: 173},
'2': {x: 177, y: 415}
};

var ss = r.set();

for(var i=0; i < data.values.length; i++){
    var s = r.set();

    s.push(r.path("M "+ coord[i].x +" "+ coord[i].y +" L 247 247 z"));
    s.push(r.circle(coord[i].x, coord[i].y, 50).attr({fill: '#fff', stroke: '#00adef', 'stroke-width': 2}));
    s.push(r.text(coord[i].x, coord[i].y-41).attr({'font': '12px Arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', fill: '#474747', text: data.values[i].name}));
    s.push(r.text(coord[i].x, coord[i].y-19).attr({'font': '28px Arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', fill: '#00adef', text: data.values[i].grade}));

    ss.push(s);
}
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So let me make sure I understand you correctly:

You want to be able to:

(1) change properties on all of the circles at the same time by updating one set object. For example

```
ss.translate(10,10)
```

moves all of the circles 10px right and 10px down.

(2) change properties on individual circles to move the circle (and it's associated path and text elements).

```
ss[0].move(10, 10)
```

moves the first circle only.

Does the following accomplish what you want?

```
var allCircles = r.set();
var circles = [];

for(var i=0; i < data.values.length; i++){
    var s = r.set();

    s.push(r.path("M "+ coord[i].x +" "+ coord[i].y +" L 247 247 z"));
    s.push(r.circle(coord[i].x, coord[i].y, 50).attr({fill: '#fff', stroke: '#00adef', 'stroke-width': 2}));
    s.push(r.text(coord[i].x, coord[i].y-41).attr({'font': '12px Arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', fill: '#474747', text: data.values[i].name}));
    s.push(r.text(coord[i].x, coord[i].y-19).attr({'font': '28px Arial', 'font-weight': 'bold', fill: '#00adef', text: data.values[i].grade}));

    circles.push(s);
    for(var j = 0; j < s.length; j++) {
        allCircles.push(s[j]);
    }
}
```

You can then move all of the circles at once by:

```
allCircles.translate(10, 10);
```

and move an individual circle by:

```
circles[0].translate(10, 10);
```

Am I understanding what you're trying to accomplish correctly?

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what i'm trying to do. Though I am more interested in just being able to do something with a particular circle (and associated text labels), having the ability to do stuff to the whole lot is handy. Your code works fine in the latest version of FF 3 but it seems to crash chrome :(

Answer (score 2):

I took bbrame's code and played with it. Two things I learned:

- You can have nested sets (a set of sets).
- You can refer to the items in a set just like you refer to items in an array...

i.e.,

```
circle_set[2];
```

Here's how I tested:

```
// the set of sets
circ_set = paper.set();

for (i=1; i<21; i++) {

    // an empty set
    var circ = paper.set();

    // add some concentric circles to the set
    circ.push(
        paper.circle(150+10*i, 50, 9).attr({fill: 'green'}),
        paper.circle(150+10*i, 50, 7).attr({fill: 'yellow'}),
        paper.circle(150+10*i, 50, 5).attr({fill: 'orange'}),
        paper.circle(150+10*i, 50, 3).attr({fill: 'red'})
    );

    // give all the circles a white outline
    circ.attr({stroke: 'white'});

    // add each set of circles to a new set (a set of sets)
    circ_set.push(circ);
}

// translate a single set of circles
circ_set[0].translate(0,10);

// translate all sets of circles
circ_set.translate(0,10);
```

Comment: which version of raphael was this? 2.0 deals with nested sets far better than 1.x (which is what I was using when I posted this question)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps make the outer set a plane old javascript array, and render each set in a loop.

Comment: I have tried that but the outer set ends up being 'blank'. The raphael docs say that a set 'doesn’t create any elements for itself in the page.'. I guess I'm limited to using raphael sets.